# Where to upgrade knowledge in Laravel and Design Patterns?

Tags: php, laravel, service

I know that this question is probably not for StackOverflow, but I really don' know where to ask for an advice.

I just found a new job for maintaining a project on Laravel. I wonder how much and how good the code of that project is. Everywhere services, each controller is using this services, configuration from `config` folder that is customized to project. Dependency injection, modularity and so on. I am using Laravel for 2 months and basically I'm newbie, I'm using just basic things from Laravel's documentation, and write a good part of my code in Controller, which I know that is a bad practice.

Where I can study and advance in this spheres? I want to be able to understand and design my projects with same modularity, strong OOP principles, services, and dependency injection. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a question for StackOverflow, but check out https://laracasts.com/

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off, you really must understand those key points:

First of hopefully you know how to write code following some psr standards, if not then learn [psr-4 standards](https://docs.opnsense.org/development/guidelines/psr2.html)

Without strong OOP understanding, like inheritance, dependency injection, dependency inversion, Inversion of control in php (Laravel IOC container), interfaces, its really hard to write code at that level or high level code.

Without OOP understanding learning design patterns just does not work.

To start off I would suggest you this excelent [php book.](http://web-algarve.com/books/MySQL%20&%20PHP/PHP%20Objects,%20Patterns,%20and%20Practice,%204th%20Edition.pdf)

Then move on on learning some design patterns, those are like tools on your belt start of by learning:

> 1. Template pattern,
> 2. Addapter pattern,
> 3. Chain of responsibility pattern,
> 4. Decorator pattern,

After you have those, move on learning how to write hight level code, or code that does not depends on low level code implementation.

Then move on to [SOLID principles](http://jokiruiz.com/software/solid-principles-php/)